# Partial output with reversed question marks when sending SMS with GSM900A module

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, gsm

I am using Arduino Uno along with GSM 900A Module to send SMS to my phone. This is the code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 10);

void setup()
{
  mySerial.begin(9600);   // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module  
  Serial.begin(9600);    // Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor (Arduino)
  delay(100);
}


void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available()>0)
   switch(Serial.read())
  {
    case 's':
      mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
     delay(1000);  // Delay of 1 second
     mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+91xxxxxxxxxx\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile number 91 is country code
     delay(1000);
     mySerial.println("Hi");// The SMS text you want to send
     delay(100);
     mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z for saying the end of sms to  the module 
      delay(1000);
      break;




    case 'r':
      mySerial.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0"); // AT Command to receive a live SMS
      delay(1000);
      break;
  }

 if (mySerial.available()>0)
   Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

This is the output I get 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpUWI.jpg

The GSM Module is showing Blue Light for Status and Yellow Light is stable for network meaning that the network is good for the module. Also, the TX light on Uno glows continuously but the RX light never glows

Comment: Does https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9483/how-to-communicate-the-arduino-board-with-sim900 help?

Comment: What do you expect instead to receive from your GSM Module?

Comment: @datafiddler https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUcrrCJd1sY. Please skip to 3:30

Comment: @blt Thanks but it is of little help as the arduino is interfacing with the GSM correctly but I am not getting the desired output and result ,i.e. an SMS on my phone from the GSM

Comment: in that youtube link @3:30 you miss 2 chars, but without those reversed `?`  Most text works well, however. Correct?

Comment: yes correct @datafiddler

Comment: After the `>` in the video it says `+CMGS : 43` and then `OK`. That never happens in my case @datafiddler

Comment: I would remove the Arduino part of your problem and connect directly with a terminal. Figure out what commands to give the device then get the Arduino to send those commands.

Answer (score 0):

you should connect it at 115200 baud rate, and if you want to change the baud rate, command it to do so while you are on default baud rate.
AT+IPR=9600   -- to change it
AT&W          -- to save the change

and lowering the baud rate is crucial if using software serial. (the second command should be sent after reconnecting at 9600, since the first command changes the baud rate)

Answer (score -1):

In my experience this is due to power supply issues (noise and lack of power). Try to power up the modem using at least 2A external power supply and use multiple 10nF or 100nF capacitors parallel to the VCC GND pins of the modem.